# How to turn a Verbatim into an itemize environment?

Tags: xetex, itemize, fancyvrb

I'm designing a class of documents that always has the same elements, among them two unordered lists, the contents of which need to be manually copy-pasted into the document. Since this is going to be used by people who aren't used to anything but basic MSWord, I'm trying to hide as much of the complex stuff as possible in the cls file.

My best attempt so far looks like this:

`.cls` file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{formtemplate}[2018/08/23 XeLaTeX-Class]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{scrbase}
\DefineFamily{formtemplate}
\DefineFamilyMember{formtemplate}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}%
\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{babel}}
\FamilyProcessOptions{formtemplate}\relax

\LoadClass[usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage[includehead,margin=0.7cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{forloop}

\setmainfont[BoldFont={CalibriB.ttf}]{Calibri.ttf}
\setmonofont[BoldFont={CalibriB.ttf}]{Calibri.ttf}
\geometry{headheight=0mm,headsep=-5mm}

\newcommand{\Left}[1]{%
    \fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\textbf{#1}%
}
\newlength{\wL}\newlength{\wLM}\newlength{\wM}\newlength{\wMR}\newlength{\wR}
\newcommand{\Prep}{%
    \settowidth{\wL}{\Left{Contact: }}
    \settowidth{\wLM}{\Left{Requirements: }}
    \deflength{\wM}{\wLM-1.05\wL}
    \deflength{\wMR}{\textwidth-1.05\wL}
    \deflength{\wR}{\textwidth-1.02\wLM}
}
\newcommand{\What}[1]{%
    \csgdef{whatval}{\expandafter#1}%
}

\setlist{noitemsep,leftmargin=8pt,topsep=0pt,labelsep=0.5ex}

\newcounter{reqc}
\setcounter{reqc}{1}
\newcounter{reqi}
\newcommand{\setreq}[1]{%
    \csgdef{req\the\value{reqc}}{#1}%
    \stepcounter{reqc}%
}
\newenvironment{Requirements}{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment%
    \renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{\setreq{##1}}%
    \begin{BVerbatim}
}{%
    \end{BVerbatim}
}
\newcommand{\reqval}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.99\wR}%
    \begin{itemize}%
    \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont%
    \forloop{reqi}{1}{\value{reqi}<\value{reqc}}{%
        \item{\csuse{req\the\value{reqi}}}%
    }%
    \end{itemize}%
    \vspace{0.5ex}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand{\Show}{%
    \noindent%
    $\;$\\
    \begin{tabu} {@{}p{\wL}@{}p{\wM}@{}p{\wR}@{}}%
        \Left{What:} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}r@{}}{\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont\textbf{\whatval}}\\\tabuphantomline\tabucline{3-}
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\parbox[t][][t]{\wLM}{\Left{Requirements:}}} & \reqval\\\tabuphantomline\tabucline{3-}
    \end{tabu}%
}
```

`.tex` file

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=10pt,pagesize,en]{formtemplate}
\begin{document}
\Prep
\What{Some kind of labeling}
\begin{Requirements}
Some normal item point
A longer item point that might require multiple requirement lines but does not contain hyphens
A line with a pesky error-causing hyphen
Another normal line
Another hyphen-related erroring line
Last line
\end{Requirements}
\Show
\end{document}
```

The problem with the current state is that it forgets what hyphens are.
[image]

Here's the part of the logs that seems relevant:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\requirement3 ->A line with a pesky error-
                                          causing hyphen
l.14 \Show

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\requirement5 ->Another hyphen-
                               related erroring line
l.14 \Show

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Edit: Hyphens aren't the only characters disappearing. Commas do as well. Semicolons produce error messages but display properly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If I understand, you are using a verbatim environment to allow each line to be an item. If that's the case, why don't you use something with `\obeylines`?

Comment: How do you suggest that would work? I'd still need to somehow put a bullet point in front of each line, and my TeX-illiterate colleagues would need to know/remember to escape ampersands(&)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pseudo verbatim approach that doesn't disable TeX's line breaking, at the cost of not allowing some special characters (namely `\`, `{` and `}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\VBI@indent
\newbox\VBI@box
\newtoks\VBI@everypar
\newenvironment{verbitemize}{%
  \let\VBI@tilde~% Save the tilde
  \setbox\VBI@box\hbox{\hss$\bullet$\VBI@tilde\hss}% Save the bullet box
  \ifdim\parindent > \wd\VBI@box
    \setbox\VBI@box\hb@xt@\parindent{\unhbox\VBI@box}%
  \fi
  \VBI@indent\wd\VBI@box% Measure the hanging indentation
  \parindent\z@% Remove paragraph indentation
  \obeylines% Make ^^M active
  \VBI@everypar{% Add a few tokens to \everypar:
    \copy\VBI@box% $\bullet$^
    \hangindent\VBI@indent% Hanging indentation
    \hangafter\@ne}%
  \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\VBI@tokn
    \expandafter\VBI@check@minipage\the\everypar\relax\@nnul
  \def\VBIdo{% List of special characters to be allowed in this speudo-verbatim mode
    \do\$\do\&\do\#\do\^\do\_\do\~%
  }% BEWARE! \do\\, \do\{, and \do\} CANNOT be used here
  \let\do\@makeother\VBIdo
}{}
\def\VBI@check@minipage#1\@nnul{%
  \ifx\VBI@tokn\@minipagefalse
    \everypar{\@minipagefalse\the\VBI@everypar
                   \everypar{\the\VBI@everypar}}%
  \else
    \everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\the\VBI@everypar}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

\begin{verbitemize}
  Some normal item point
  A longer item point that might require multiple requirement lines but does not contain hyphens
  A line with a \st{pesky error-causing hyphen} not anymore \texttt{=D}
  Another normal line
  Another hyphen-related erroring line
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  A line with special characters: $ & # ^ _ ~
  Last line
\end{verbitemize}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

The environment does a few verbatim-like settings before typesetting something:

First it saves the `~` in `\VBI@tilde` to allow the user to write `~`:

```
  \let\VBI@tilde~%
```

then it creates a box `\VBI@box` that contains the bullet:

```
  \setbox\VBI@box\hb@xt@\parindent{\hss$\bullet$\VBI@tilde\hss}%
```

and use its width to measure the hanging indentation:

```
  \VBI@indent\wd\VBI@box
```

Here we don't want to use normal paragraph indentation:

```
  \parindent\z@
```

Now we make new lines active, so each one will insert a `\par` token

```
  \obeylines
```

then after each new line the `\VBI@everypar` token list will be executed:

```
  \VBI@everypar{%
    \copy\VBI@box
    \hangindent\VBI@indent
    \hangafter\@ne}%
```

but before inserting this into `\everypar` we need to check if we're inside a `minipage`. The `minipage` clears the `\everypar` token list, so we need to check. I used a macro `\VBI@check@minipage` that will look inside the `\everypar` token list and check if `\@minipagefalse` is there.

Now we only need to make special characters usable without escaping:

```
  \def\VBIdo{\do\$\do\&\do\#\do\^\do\_\do\~}%
  \let\do\@makeother\VBIdo
```

this will allow `$`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, and `~`. If you don't want any of them, just remove the entry. Beware that `\`, `{` and `}` should not be used here, otherwise the environment will not find the `\end{verbitemize}`.

#### Edit:

Fixed for working inside `minipage`s and in cases the `\parindent` is smaller than the bullet point.

Comment: Nice, the best of both worlds! I'll try it right away! And even with an explanation for its constituent parts. :D Btw: What's the \tracingall \tracingnone for?

Comment: It seems to need `tabu*` instead of plain `tabu` and the width of the bullet point seems to be 0 if the cell spacing is 0, but it looks promising. The easiest solution to that would seem to be to wrap it in a minipage, but wrapping it in a minipage (inside or outside a table) causes all bullet points except the first one to disappear.

Comment: @joelproko It won't work with `tabu` because it collects the contents as arguments, and tokenizes the end of lines as spaces, so `verbitemize` (and any verbatim-like environment) won't work (see page 7 of the `tabu` manual). You can wrap the `tabu` in `{\obeylines ... }`, then the bullet points will work, but special characters won't. I fixed the environment for working inside a `minipage`. It turns out that `minipage` clears the `\everypar` tokens, in which `verbitemize` relies to make the bullet points. `\tracingall` and `\tracingnone` turn TeX's logging on and off (I forgot to delete them).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something along these lines.  I created a new `verbitemize` environment, using the constructs of the `verbatimbox` package, and use `!` as the linebreak character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\catcode`!=\active
\def!{\newline\mbox{}\hspace{2em}}
\catcode`!=12 %
\newcommand\vbsetup{$\bullet$~}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{verbitemize}{%
\catcode`!=\active %
\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
\let\my@par\par%
\def\verbatim@processline{%
{\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
\@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
\hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
\verbatim\verbbox@inner%
}
{%
\endverbatim%
\global\def\@tmp{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent Here is normal text!

\begin{verbitemize}[\vbsetup]
This is a test
Now another.
Here I insert! manual line breaks! with an! exclamation point.
Finally, the last line
\end{verbitemize}

\noindent Back!to!normal!text!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but it refuses to be put into a minipage or table cell.

Comment: @joelproko It can be put into a `minipage`.  Something different will be required, though, for a `tabular` cell.  In the `verbatimbox` package, see `verbbox` rather than `verbnobox`.  The verbatim "box" can be built outside of the `tabular` and then *inserted* into the `tabular`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{VerbItem}{%
    \renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\textbullet}%
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,breakatwhitespace,breaklines,
            numbers=left,numbersep=2pt,xleftmargin=0.75em}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{VerbItem}
Some normal item point
A longer item point that might require multiple requirement lines but does not contain hyphens
A line with a pesky error-causing hyphen
Another normal line
Another hyphen-related erroring line
Last line
\end{VerbItem}

\noindent
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks promising. Does it behave properly in minipages and/or table cells and is there a way to leave the linebreaking to babel? Also, how do I remove that indent in the auto-broken line?

Comment: `breakindent=0pt` -> see documentation! hyphenation is not possible and inside minipages it can be used.